# issue with threading crashes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a crash log that I haven't been able to decipher:

[image]

If I had to guess this had to do me doing a UI upgrade on the background thread. Can anyone enlighten me or possibly give me more clue on what this crash log means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep. It looks like your trying to update a webview on a background thread, To check if this is the case, find wherever you are updating your UIWebView and put this line of code in.

```
NSLog(@"[%@ %@] Is Main Thread? %@",NSStringFromClass([self class]), NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),[NSThread isMainThread]?@"YES":@"NO");
```

It will print the name of the class, function, and if you are on the main thread or not.

If you are not on the main thread, then you can do a simple if(!mainthread) then performSelectorOnMainThread  to execute the relevant code on the main thread.

Comment: how do you know that it's updating a UI from a background thread?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using ARC the first thing to do is make sure you run the analyze on your code (Product > Analyze). I am guessing the issue is you have some reference count and the background thread is trying to use something that has been released.